# Why can I start only certain programms minimized and others not?

Tags: autohotkey

For example when I want to start word minimized it works just fine with this code:

```
Run, WINWORD.exe , , Min
```

But when I do the same with opera it opens as a normal window.

```
Run, opera.exe , , Min
```

Any explaination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is found straight from the [documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm):

> **Note**: Some applications (e.g. Calc.exe) do not obey the requested startup state and thus Max/Min/Hide will have no effect.

Of course with `WinMinimize`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMinimize.htm)</sup> you can just minimize the application yourself after launching it.